# template_name не имеет атрибута?

Tags: python, django

Учусь...)) 
Серевер запускается. При переходе на страницу приложения вот такая ошибка

```css
  File "F:\django\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatc
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\django\test_django\courses_django\lesson_seventh\views.py", line 24, in get
    return render(request, self.tamplate_name, ctx)
AttributeError: 'MainView' object has no attribute 'tamplate_name'
[02/May/2019 23:06:44] "GET /lesson-seventh/ HTTP/1.1" 500 75926
```

вот кусок views.py

```css
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import UserCreateForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from .forms import UserCreateForm
from lesson_sixth.models import Human
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login
""" Функция для установки сессионного ключа.
По нему Django будет определять, выполнил ли вход пользователь
"""
class MainView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'main_seventh.html'

    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            humans = Human.objects.all()
            ctx = {}
            ctx['humans'] = humans
            return render(request, self.tamplate_name, ctx)
        else:
            return render(request, self.tamplate_name, {})
```

вот main_seventh.html

```css
<body>

  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <a href="logout">'выйти({{user.username}})'</a>
  {% else %}
  <a href="register">Регистрация на сайте</a>
  <a href="login">Авторизация</a>
  {% endif %}

  {% for elem in humans %}
  <p>Name-{{elem.name}}</p>
  <p>Surname-{{elem.surname}}</p>
  <p>Company-{{elem.company}}</p>
  {% endfor %}


</body>
```

Куда копать не могу понять...((

Comment: Уже вторая такая ситуация со значениями в списках. Похоже Атом не спроста выделяет красным эту часть...

Comment: Не tamplate_name, а template_name

Comment: @andreymal  спасибо огромное...